# How to add an extension to a URL

Tags: html

I have a search box where user searches for his Name, when he submits he has to be taken to a new page where he sees information under his name. I used the code below:

```html
export function logon_click() {

    let word = $w("#searchBar").value; 

    local.setItem("searchWord", word); 

    wixLocation.to(`/userdata`); 

}
```

Let me explain the code, the user will search for a Number for example 12345, when he submits I need than number (search word) to be added to the URL on my code, which in this case is: `wixLocation.to(`/userdata`);` All i need is to have this extension `/12345` on my code.

the link on a real website will look like: www.google.com/12345 where by 12345 is the search word or number.

My question is, what is missing on my code because if I click the button I get the link like www.google.com and this extension `/12345` from the search box is missing. What should I add on the code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change this https://mtthmatthie.wixsite.com/website-3/userdata/50001 to something like https://mtthmatthie.wixsite.com/50001 ? Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Let me give another example: I use this link: www.website.com, User 1 accesses his account by this link: www.website.com/123, User2 access by this: www.website.com/456, User3 by: www.website.com/789, what is changing here is the last part which I need to call username or account number. but to do this I want to have an edit box where users enter their usernames and be taken to a relevant account.

Comment: Ok got your point, in reality i don't know how wix works , but if there is a routing class in wix then all you need is to write the url to redirect to/:id and then you navigate using href or ehatever by adding url plus the textbox value, but if there is no routing class, then you can't achieve it except with url parameters like https://mtthmatthie.wixsite.com/website-3/userdata?acc_num=50001

Comment: Ok may you take a look again on the edit, I have some code and close to the idea using the search function method

Comment: wixLocation.to(/userdata?any=12); try this and see the result

Comment: Got an error, what does that ?any=12 mean

Comment: Its a url parameter to pass data from page to page any is the parameter you can call from page and accuire from another page and obtain its value, but since it gave an error , that means there is routing wix and it coupd be achieved, i will make a fast search and brb.

Comment: var s= 'acc_nb=50001' ; Then wixLocation.to("https://redirecttothissite.com?" + s);

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-creating-a-router&ved=2ahUKEwjo6ufZ4sLoAhWImHIEHfxoChIQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1pJ4zCwPMR_A6pq-VaXEuD and this link is for using routing in ur app if u need it for future work

Comment: Thank you for all your tips, I have came to a solution, that was really a minor thing that I have discovered through your tips, thank you very much

Comment: No problem welcome anytime

Answer (score 0):

```html
export function logon_click() {

    let word = $w("#searchBar").value; 

    local.setItem("searchWord", word); 

    wixLocation.to(`/userdata/${word}`);
    

}
```

This solves my problem...